# How to only consider the first day of any month?

Tags: excel, vba

how can I make sure that this code below only considers dates where the day is the 01. ?
**Meaning:** only dates like 01.01.,01.02.,01.03, etc ?

The dates are stored in **column 8** of my wb.Source. They are **true dates**.

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click() ' update averages




 Const YEAR = 2019

' open source workbook
Dim fname As String, wbSource As Workbook, wsSource As Worksheet
fname = Me.TextBox1.Text

If Len(fname) = 0 Then
   MsgBox "No file selected", vbCritical, "Error"
   Exit Sub
End If

Set wbSource = Workbooks.Open(fname, False, True) ' no link update, read only
Set wsSource = wbSource.Sheets("Sheet1") ' change to suit

Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Sheets("Table 2") '

' scan down source workbook calc average





Dim iRow As Long, lastRow As Long
Dim sMth As String, iMth As Long
Dim count(12) As Long, sum(12) As Long


lastRow = wsSource.Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
For iRow = 1 To lastRow

  If IsDate(CDate(wsSource.Cells(iRow, 8).Value)) _
        And IsNumeric(wsSource.Cells(iRow, 30)) Then
  If Day(wsSource.Cells(iRow, 8)) = 1 Then
        iMth = Month(wsSource.Cells(iRow, 8))
        sum(iMth) = sum(iMth) + wsSource.Cells(iRow, 30)
        count(iMth) = count(iMth) + 1 '


      End If
End If

    Next
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Maybe just use `Day(date)` :

```
if Day( date ) = 1 then 'It is the first day of the month
```

Your code would be :

```
Set wsSource = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

If IsDate(CDate(wsSource.Cells(iRow, 8).value)) _
            And IsNumeric(wsSource.Cells(iRow, 30)) Then
      if Day(wsSource.Cells(iRow, 8)) = 1 then 
            iMth = Month(wsSource.Cells(iRow, 8))   
            sum(iMth) = sum(iMth) + wsSource.Cells(iRow, 30) 
            count(iMth) = count(iMth) + 1 '
       end if
End If
```

Comment: Sorry for asking, but how do I add it to my code exactly? Getting error messages all the time...

Comment: @PlutoX if Day(wsSource.Cells(iRow, 8).value) = 1 then

Comment: I get an error : "type mismatch" for this part of the code:


If Day(wsSource.Cells(iRow, 8).Value) = 1 _
            And IsNumeric(wsSource.Cells(iRow, 30)) Then

Comment: thanks. No erros this time but no return either :) Somehow there are no results anymore provided by the code

Comment: @PlutoX are those values always date ? If yes use CDate()

Comment: Again error: "type missmatch" at " If IsDate(CDate(wsSource.Cells(iRow, 8).Value)) _
            And IsNumeric(wsSource.Cells(iRow, 30)) Then"

Comment: Can you provide me a dataset

Comment: I've updated the post with a screenshot. I've changed the date format to dd.mm.yyyy to fot my worksheet. But it still return nothing.. You can ignore column AD.

Comment: @PlutoX use Debug.print and print isnumeric() does it return true sometimes ?

Comment: Add the argument isnumeric(wssource.cells(irow,30))

Comment: "Object variable not set"

Comment: @PlutoX just add   `Debug.pring IsNumeric(wsSource.Cells(iRow, 30))` in your code insade your For Loop and run it !

Comment: I just dont get it, tried to add it instead of the for loop - still getting errors... thank you but I dont want to waste even more of your time

Comment: @PlutoX I got it, what is the name of your worksheet ? `wsSource` is not defined in the code you gave us

Comment: its just "Sheet1"

Comment: I've updated the post with the complete code, maybe it helps