# Copy rows from one workbook to another if condition is fulfilled

Tags: excel, vba

how can I copy/paste rows from one workbook to another if the following conditions are met:
Copy all rows from the source workbook(wb.Source,sheet1) if they are from the actual month(column 8 containing true dates) and paste them to my master workbook(Wb) in sheet 3. Only copy the rows which have the first day of the month as date in column 8.

**Example:**

Lets say today is the 14.05.2020.

Triggering the macro would copy all rows from the source workbook with the date 01.05.2020(column 8) and paste them to wb in Sheet 3.

So the macro needs to refer to the Today function to able to say which month it actually is right now, and then in the next step to copy the rows which are frim the same month BUT only from the first day of said month.

Would appreciate any help!

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()





Dim fname As String, wbSource As Workbook, wsSource As Worksheet
    fname = Me.TextBox1.Text

    If Len(fname) = 0 Then
       MsgBox "No file selected", vbCritical, "Error"
       Exit Sub
    End If

    Set wbSource = Workbooks.Open(fname, False, True) ' no link update, read only
    Set wsSource = wbSource.Sheets("Sheet1") ' change to suit

    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("Table 3")



    ' Set your source and destination worksheets as objects here

    Set wsSource = wbSource.Sheets("Sheet1")


    Dim i As Long, destination_row As Long
    Dim source_rng As Range, destination_rng As Range
    destination_row = 1

    For i = 1 To 10 ' See note below regarding for vs while loop for this
        ' Check dates only against cells that contain date values (in case there is a non-date value in one of the cells)
        If VarType(wsSource.Cells(i, 8)) = vbDate Then

            ' Condition checks that the date is today
            If Format(Now, "yyyy/mm/dd") = Format(wsSource.Cells(i, 8).Value2, "yyyy/mm/dd") Then

                ' Set source and destination ranges
                Set source_rng = wsSource.Range(wsSource.Cells(i, 1), wsSource.Cells(i, 10000))
                Set destination_rng = ws.Range(ws.Cells(destination_row, 1), destination_sheet.Cells(destination_row, 10000))

                source_rng.Copy destination_rng ' Alternatively use destination_rng.Value2 = source_rng.Value2
                destination_row = destination_row + 1 ' Iterate the destination row so that the next copy outputs to the next row

            End If
        End If
    Next i



     ' close source worbook no save
    wbSource.Close False


End Sub
```

Comment: Always helps to post your current code - it would make answering much easier otherwise we can just refer you to the answer you already got here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61800272/how-to-only-consider-the-first-day-of-any-month

Comment: `Dateserial(year(date),month(date),1)` gives you the first day of the current month

Answer (score 0):

The question was a little vague as to the formatting of the worksheets (which columns contain data, where you want to begin printing, if you know how many rows the source data is, if all cells within the data range are populated, etc.), but I've written an example here that can be tweaked to fit the worksheets you're using.

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopyRows()

    ' Set your source and destination worksheets as objects here
    Dim source_sheet As Worksheet, destination_sheet As Worksheet
    Set source_sheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("A")
    Set destination_sheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("B")

    Dim i As Long, destination_row As Long
    Dim source_rng As Range, destination_rng As Range
    destination_row = 1

    For i = 1 To 10 ' See note below regarding for vs while loop for this
        ' Check dates only against cells that contain date values (in case there is a non-date value in one of the cells)
        If VarType(source_sheet.Cells(i, 8)) = vbDate Then

            ' Condition checks that the date is today
            If Format(Now, "yyyy/mm/dd") = Format(source_sheet.Cells(i, 8).Value2, "yyyy/mm/dd") Then

                ' Set source and destination ranges
                Set source_rng = source_sheet.Range(source_sheet.Cells(i, 1), source_sheet.Cells(i, 10))
                Set destination_rng = destination_sheet.Range(destination_sheet.Cells(destination_row, 1), destination_sheet.Cells(destination_row, 10))
                source_rng.Copy destination_rng ' Alternatively use destination_rng.Value2 = source_rng.Value2
                destination_row = destination_row + 1 ' Iterate the destination row so that the next copy outputs to the next row

            End If
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

I've used sheets "A" and "B" as proxies for your source and destination worksheets. You need to set these objects to your actual source and destination worksheets in your code.

I've also initalized destination_row as 1, assuming you want the copied rows to be printed starting on the first row of the destination worksheet, but this can be set to 2 (if there are headers) or to any row you prefer the output starts on. You may want to add additional code to find the next empty row if you want the new rows to be added underneath whatever data already exists in the worksheet.

The for loop is written as a basic example, assuming that you know how many rows of data there are. If you expect the size of the source range to change (i.e. rows are often added and/or removed), you would want to either determine a final row before starting the loop (by using xlUp/xlDown or similar), or use a while loop instead of a for loop (if there is a column that is always populated that you can use as part of the while condition).

In the section where the source_rng and destination_rng are set, replace the numbers 1 and 10 with the first and last columns of the data (for example, if the data starts on column 3 and finishes on column 15, these should be changed to 3 and 15 respectively).

Comment: thanks so far! I've adjusted your code to fit my worksheets. After a couple of errors I got it working. Only problem is that the code does not return anything. Any idea why? See code in initial post.

Comment: Hi - not really sure what you mean by "return" in this context?
Also please note what I said about the line with the for loop and the range selection columns - these will need to be adjusted depending on the characteristics of your data.

Comment: sorry, I mean that no rows have been copied and pasted. My destination sheet is empty. I've adjusted even the date format to dd.mm.yyyy to fit my worksheet, still no results My source sheet has over 14k rows that why I adjusted the range to 1 - 15000

Comment: The date format won't matter as it is converting both dates to the same format - the exact format doesn't matter as it's just for comparison, as long as they're both being converted to the same format. Excel stores dates as a numerical value so the underlying values of dates on the worksheet is the same no matter how you have them presented.

Comment: I think you may have adjusted the wrong numbers. The for loop should be adjusted based on the numbers of ROWS of data (I still see it reading "for i = 1 to 10") and the destination range setting should be adjusted based on the number of COLUMNS (you've adjusted to 10000, which seems incorrect).